# Can't access .png files in Terminal from Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, terminal

Let me know if you need more code than this!

I can run the program perfectly fine in Eclipse. But once I access the files and run java Frame in Terminal, it only shows part of my game. It doesn't show any of the .png files.

Here is my main method:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
public static String title = "Tower Defense Alpha";
public static Dimension size = new Dimension(700, 550);


public Frame() {
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    init();

}

public void init(){

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));

    Screen screen = new Screen(this);
    add(screen);

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Frame frame = new Frame();


}
```

}

And here is how I am accessing the files in Eclipse, which doesn't seem to work in Terminal:

```
for (int i=0; i<tileset_ground.length; i++) {
        tileset_ground[i] = new ImageIcon("res/tileset_ground.png").getImage();
        tileset_ground[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_ground[i].getSource(), 
                                        new CropImageFilter(0, 26*i, 26, 26)));
    }
```

Comment: Which command are you running your program with? Which is the directory/folder you're launching it?

Comment: The command I am using is "javac *.java" then "java Frame" and my files are in a folder called Client, and in a folder inside Client called "src" so its in the directory "Client\src"

Comment: Sorry I meant the .png files are in a folder called "Client\res" the Frame.java file is in "Client\src"

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:applet]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is that on the Terminal, the program is being run from the `Client/src folder` and thus it tries to look for the images on `Client/src/res`, which does not exist.

Eclipse on the other hand, keeps separate folders and launches the program using the project folder as its root folder:

```
Client
|
+-- bin (classes compiled by Eclipse)
|
+-- res (images)
|
+-- src (source code)
```

By running `javac *.java` while on the `src` folder you're creating a copy of the compiled classes on the `src` folder.

On the Terminal you need to return to the Client folder and launch your program from there with `java -classpath bin Frame`

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked! Thank you so much. Now is there anyway I can make a Driver class that does that code for me? I want to just be able to go to the Client folder and type "java Driver" and have it run that code.

Comment: To do that you'll need to create a launcher script for running your program from the command line, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660103/483566

Comment: Is there a way for me to move around the files so I can just use "java Frame" and have it work?

Comment: You would have to copy the compiled classes to the Client folder, so that the current folder contains the file Frame.class and the "res" folder (which is already on the right place)

Comment: Awesome. It works! Thank you so much. I don't know why that was stumping me for so long. Thanks again!